# M2E Pro Listing Items to Ebay is Slow and unreliable on Ubuntu Apache

Tags: php, apache, magento, ubuntu, m2e-pro

Whenever I list new items to eBay from M2E Pro it takes about 5 minutes to list one item.  The most I can list is four at a time otherwise the status bar will stop progressing and the items will not get listed.  Sometimes I can only list one at a time with the same situation happening.  I thought it was my hardware but I just bought a new server and everything is much faster (load time) except listing to eBay.  On my old system I started using ubuntu 12.04 and upgraded through 13.10.  I've also been upgrading magento since 1.7 through 1.8.  I have been upgrading M2E Pro throughout the same time frame.  I'm currently using ubuntu 12.04 with magento CE 1.8 and the newest version of M2E Pro.  I've tried to tweak apache and php to no avail. I appreciate anyone who is willing to try and help!

Comment: provide some code or snapshot with question

Comment: Code from what?  My php.ini?  .htaccess?  I've looked for a M2E Pro log but I cannot find any.  Basically what happens is when I list an item using M2E Pro to ebay the progress bar will not proceed and it will stop listing items.  There isn't any error or anything.

Comment: What internet speeds do you get from speedtest.net

Answer (score 0):

I found this is an Magento problem ON my VPS. I could not get Magento to run worth a S**& with my PHP.ini set to apache. I had to change it to fast cgi. I don't know why, but I think it is an ownership:group problem as far as I got. Look at Mod_secrity & whitelist. I had to set in my .htaccess.

```
php_value suhosin.session.encrypt Off
# mod_security rules my IP
SetEnvIfNoCase REMOTE_ADDR ^76\.182\.185\.215$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off

############################################
## adjust memory limit

php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 36000
post_max_size 512M
upload_max_filesize 512M

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off


########################################### not sure about this one since php5
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects
php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_security.c>

###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
```

Other things to do is set reindex to manual. Compile and enable
Hope this helps
James Niland
Niland Enterpise LLC